# Accessing structure array data of form1 in form2

Tags: c#, winforms, structure

Here is my question.

I've a custom structure as follows in form1.

```
public struct MessageInfo
    {
        public int MessagePosition;
        public string UserID;
        public string PutDateTime;
        public string ID;
        public string MessageLength;
        public string MessageData;
    }
```

I've multiple structure data, which I'm storing in a array of structures as below

```
public MessageInfo[] messages;
```

and I'm storing multiple data of each structure in the array. 
Now, I want to access this structure array, which has data in form2. Any advise how do i do this?

I tried the below in form1, but I'm unable to access the data in form2.

```
public MessageInfo[] GetMessageInfo
    {
        get { return messages;}
    }
```

I get the following exception.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'form1.MessageInfo[]' to 'form2.MessageInfo[]'
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: is your `form1` open as well ?

Comment: @Habib, yes, I've both the forms open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is telling that you have defined the `struct` in **both forms**. You need to define the struct `MessageInfo` in **one place** and refer the same from both forms.

Comment: Thanks @Habib, dumb me.. I got it. Thanks.